# How to fix mdadm: inactive RAID1 arrays, after unplugging one of the drives in both cases?

Tags: debian, mdadm, software-raid

## TL;DR

I need to read and write from / to 2 of my `mdadm` RAID1 arrays after unplugging one of the drives in both cases and commenting them out of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` + updating `initramfs`, of course.

---

## System

**OS**: GNU/Linux Debian 9 (Stretch), fully updated.

**MD**: 2 `mdadm` arrays in RAID1, both of which appear upon boot as seen below.

**HW**: Unplugged one of the drives in `mdadm` RAID1 from both arrays.

---

## Upon boot they are both seen as `inactive`

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : inactive sdc1[1](S)
      1953382471 blocks super 1.2

md1 : inactive sdb1[1](S)
      976630471 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

---

## Explanation

I intentionally commented out these arrays in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
# newer drives | 2 TB
#ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=server:0 UUID=<Array UUID #0>

# older drives | 1 TB
#ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=server:1 UUID=<Array UUID #1>
```

Finally, I updated `initramfs` as follows before reboot:

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

---

## Question

How do I, temporarily speaking, make both of the arrays active and writable at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to stop those arrays:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md127 && mdadm --stop /dev/md1
```

You should see:

> ```
> mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
> mdadm: stopped /dev/md1
> ```

---

Then, you need to assemble them again:

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan
```

You should see:

> ```
> mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
> mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
> ```

---

Let's see, what we have now:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdc1[1]
      1953382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[1]
      976630464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

So, we are basically done, with the exception, that the arrays are read-only.

---

We can solve this with the following command:

```
# mdadm --readwrite /dev/md[01]
```

You should see nothing now, if the command has been successful, which you can simply verify again with:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1]
      1953382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      976630464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```